# Predicted Values From Forecast functions

Tags: forecasting

My question is very simple.

```
library(fpp)
ts <- ausbeer # seasonal with period 4 
f.seasonal <-snaive(ts, h = 20)
```

I would like to see what the beer production is in the third quarter of 2010. I can do

```
f.seasonal$mean
```

It returns the table:

```
      Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2008                 473
2009  420  390  410  473
2010  420  390  410  473
2011  420  390  410  473
2012  420  390  410  473
2013  420  390  410
```

Obviously, I can see the answer in the table. Is there a snippet of code to retain the predicted value easier from forecast objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fc <- window(f.seasonal$mean, start=c(2010,3), end=c(2010,3))
```